# Maven Checkstyle not working

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I have the following modules set in my checkstyle.xml under the TreeWalker module

```
<module name="NestedIfDepth">
  <property name="max" value="3" />
</module>
<module name="NestedTryDepth">
  <property name="max" value="3" />
</module>
```

But if i say write more than 3 nested IF statements it does not throw a checkstyle error during my maven install

The Checkstyle plugin is configured in the POM as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure Maven is using your checkstyle.xml config file?  Please provide the checkstyle plugin configuration you are using in your pom.xml.

Comment: <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8</version>
                </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

When using [Maven Checkstyle Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) with custom checks, the plugin needs to be configured with the location of the [custom checkstyle checker configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>[filename for custom checkstyle config file]</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It is already implemented, but checkstyle is still not working